# Count redis keys without fetching them in Ruby

Tags: ruby, count, redis

I'm keeping a list of online users in Redis with one key corresponding to one user. Keys are set to time out in 15 minutes, so all I have to do to see how many users have roughly been active in the past 15 minutes, I can do:

```
redisCli.keys('user:*').count
```

The problem is as the number of keys grows, the time it takes to fetch all the keys before counting them is increasing noticeably. Is there a way to count the keys without actually having to fetch all of them first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [count of keys matching a pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418529/count-of-keys-matching-a-pattern)

Comment: Can't use `wc -l` in Ruby, so that doesn't answer my question

Comment: `wc -l` is exactly like doing `.count` - the bottom line IMHO, is that there is no API in _redis_` which fetches only the count, so there is no way to do it in ruby either, as it simply wraps the public API. Look also at this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/NBRj1HOL098

Comment: I'm using RedisCloud, so I doubt I can talk them into patching redis. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can talk with us about anything but the Set/Sorted Set answer by @UriAgassi is that way to go :)

Comment: You can wrap this in a lua script and execute it server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis does not have an API for only counting keys with a specific pattern, so it is also not available in the ruby client.

What I can suggest is to have another data-structure to read to number of users from.

For instance, you can use redis's [SortedSet](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), where you can keep each user with the timestamp of its last TTL set as the `score`, then you can call `zcount` to get the current number of active users:

```
redisCli.zcount('active_users', 15.minutes.ago.to_i, Time.now.to_i)
```

From time to time you will need to clean up the old values by:

```
redisCli.zremrangebyscore 'active_users', 0, 15.minutes.ago.to_i
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative to directly indexing keys in a Set or Sorted Set, which is to use the new [SCAN command](http://redis.io/commands/scan). It depends on the use case, memory / speed tradeoff, and required precision of the count.

Another alternative is that you use Redis HyperLogLogs, see [PFADD](http://redis.io/commands/pfadd) and [PFCOUNT](http://redis.io/commands/pfcount).