# Is counting Redis keys not recommended in production even has expiration time?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I've seen post here [How to count the number of keys matching a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418529/how-to-count-the-number-of-keys-matching-a-pattern) which comments said it is not advisable to count keys in production. Which I believe is true.

My question is.. **is it still not recommended when keys expire?** expiration deletes keys.

what im trying to do is I am counting the number of active users via storing them in redis key which has expiration. Im doing it with Laravel. I need to count that matching keys for able to get the number of active users.

Any recommendation? Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be a way more pragmatic solution to rely on a `last_login` field or `last_active` field, you set in the front end. Either on using the `Laravel` application or an user activity every 15 minutes or similar. Middleware you would set on every call in your application.

```
class LastActivityMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        $user->last_activity = now();
        $user->save();

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Which would make it possible to do.

```
User::where('last_active', '>=', now()->subMinutes(15))->count();
```

The other solution would have a horrible run time, aparently break the cache and simply be a very complex solution to a simple problem.

Comment: This was my original solution and thought it would be better to use redis, im trying to explore redis more to learn its application like laravel. but I guess middleware still the best approach though hahaha. Thanks man!

Comment: I would think this is best, also redis command has to loop through all users keys, if you have millions that gotta take a while.